# Celery - implementing tasks in other module

Tags: celery, pyhook

Let's say I have two python packages

1. `producer`
2. `consumer`

they live in a different repositories (and running on separate servers)

I would like to use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/) implement some background tasks
so that `producer` will create tasks and `consumer` will execute them

Now, celery seems done that way that tasks code must be shared between `consumer` and `producer`...

Is there a way to make it possible to start celery task from producer so that `producer` never knows the actual source code of the `consumer` ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `send_task()` - I have already answered similar questions here before. The beauty of this function is that all you need to know are task names, and their parameters, and you need, naturally to have the same configuration (broker, serialization, etc).